# Can I use Chrome to debug why a Truetype font fails to load

Tags: html

I am trying to use a ttf font in a webpage and it is failing. The log tells me it failed to load but not more details (like why). I can use the font and Open it on my Mac.

Any ideas on how I might debug the issue (ie find out why the font fails) in Chrome?

Comment: Which log told you it failed to load?  The server log, or a log in the browser?  How are you referencing it from your CSS?  What MIME type are you serving the ttf file as?

Comment: It was the client log. I am adding it as a font face in the CSS.

Comment: I am using @font-face {
    font-family: FuturaBT-Bold;
    src: url("thecavalierdailywpage1/FuturaBT-Bold.ttf");
}

Answer (score 3):

The Google Chrome inspector should tell you some information about it, on the Network tab chose the font tab on the bottom and then reload your page.

[image: Google Chrome Inspector Network Tab]